# Website unavailable after resuming VM Instances

Tags: web-server, virtual-machines, wordpress, website

I use GCP to host my company wordpress website. I originally had the "free" trial for the first 3 months. When it ran out, my website was disabled. So after paying my charges on Monday, I resumed my VM instances to hopefully have my website back running. However, that was not the case and my website is still not running.. Google support said they could no longer help me, as I do not and will not purchase a support package. Can someone help me get my website back up and running? TIA!!!

Comment: There is not enough information provided, how did you setup the virtual machine, what operating system - have you confirmed the files still exist on the virtual machine (e.g. it's not just been recreated etc)?